# autoit: Add more seconds to Sleep() from a user inputted variable

Tags: autoit

I use `Sleep()` through out my script. I have added a user input that allows the user to add more seconds to the Sleep()

```
Local $iDelayInput = GUICtrlCreateInput("0", 170, 75, 13, 20)
Local $delaySeconds = GUICtrlRead($iDelayInput)
```

I am trying to figure out how I can apply that to the Sleep() I have through out my script. I have

```
Sleep(5000+$delaySeconds&000)
```

but does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the &000 is being treated like a string and being ignored, so you are probably getting only 5000 + the number the user enters. Try changing the Sleep command to this and see if it helps:

```
Sleep(5000+($delaySeconds*1000))
```

The line above takes the number entered by the user and multiplies it by 1000 to give you the number of milliseconds, then adds it to the existing 5000.

Comment: "I believe the &000 is being treated like a string ..." yes that's exactly what `&` operator does: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_operators.htm

Comment: That's not what the problem is. It is being treated as a string yes, but it's still being added, the problem is that `000` as a string is `0`, so you are only multiplying it by 10, not 1000. Furthermore, `+` has a higher precedence than `&`, so the original code is doing `(5000+$delaySeconds)*10`, which is not what was intended.